# comparing dicts with additional values

Tags: python

I have 2 lists of python dicts: realList and expectedList

I want realList to be considered equal to expectedList if there is one, and only one, "sub-dict" on realList for each dict of expectedList

By sub-dict I mean a dict with at least the same key/values, but which might have additional key/values.

so, for example:

```
realDict =     [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}]
==
expectedDict = [{'a': 1},         {'a': 2, 'b': 3}]


realDict =     [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}]
!=
expectedDict = [{'a': 2},         {'a': 2, 'b': 3}]


realDict =     [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]
!=
expectedDict = [{'a': 1}]
```

Any modules to help? Only idea I can think of is iterating over expectedDict and removing a dict from it and from realDict whenever they match. Then, in the end, both must be [].

Comment: Does the order matter?  Must `realDict[0]` always match `expectedDict[0]` or can it possibly match `expectedDict[1]`?

Comment: Are you sure your first example is correct? `there is one, and only one, "sub-dict" on realList for each dict of expectedList` suggests that for each dict in `expectedList`, there is a dict in `realList` that has one extra key. Even though this is not the case in your first example, you still call them equal

Comment: @mVChr, the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but I'm unsure how performant it is:

```
def complete_subset(real_list, expected_list):
    real_set_list = [set(d.items()) for d in real_list]
    expected_set_list = [set(d.items()) for d in expected_list]

    while len(real_set_list):
        real_len = len(real_set_list)
        i = 0
        for real_set in real_set_list:
            for expected_set in expected_set_list:
                if not len(expected_set - real_set):
                    real_set_list.remove(real_set)
                    expected_set_list.remove(expected_set)
            i = i + 1
        if i == real_len:
            break

    return (not len(real_set_list)) and (not len(expected_set_list))
```

Here are my tests:

```
print complete_subset([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}], [{'a': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}]) == True
print complete_subset([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}], [{'a': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}]) == False
print complete_subset([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}], [{'a': 1}]) == False
print complete_subset([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}], [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]) == True
print complete_subset([
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
], [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'a': 1},
    {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'j': 10},
]) == True
```

Comment: yeah, apparently there isn't a simple/"pythonic" solution. I'm accepting this one. thanks

Comment: @Lem0n Cool, I actually thought of a similar but more efficient way to do it while thinking in the shower the other day.  I haven't completely worked it out in code yet, but let me know if you want me to take a stab if you can't figure out how to make this more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

In case your two lists are to be compared element by element, you can do it this way.

```
def compare(realDict, expectedDict):
    if len(readDict) != len(expectedDict):
        return False
    for d1, d2 in zip(realDict, expectedDict):
        for key in d2:
            if key not in d1 or d1[key] != d2[key]:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: This does not allow for `one additional key`

Comment: You do not mention `one additional key` anywhere in your question. Can you clarify with some examples?

Comment: Also, if you are mentioning the fact that realDict can have more keys, that is taken care of since we only check that all keys of expectedDict are in realDict and not the other way around.